# .toggleClass not toggling a certain class, but is working on all others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a page on my website that has some navigation elements that stick on the page when the user scrolls past a certain point. There are three of them, one on the top, one on the left, and one on the right. HTML and CSS is as follows:

```
<div id="nav" class="nav">
    <!--STUFF CONTAINED IN TOP NAV BAR-->
</div>

<div class="right" id="right">
    <!--STUFF CONTAINED IN RIGHT NAV-->         
</div>

<div class="left" id="left">
    <!--STUFF CONTAINED IN LEFT NAV BAR-->
</div>


.nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 108px;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.nav_sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 45px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: url(images/backgrounds/stardust_@2X.png);
    z-index: 10;
}

.right {
    width: 200px;
    height: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -538px;
    top: 153px;
}

.right_sticky {
    width: 200px;
    height: 900px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -538px;
    top: 45px;
}

.left {
    width: 200px;
    height: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -538px;
    top: 153px;
}

.left_stick {
    width: 200px;
    height: 900px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -538px;
    top: 45px;
}
```

I then use the follow JQuery to cause these elements to stick.

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var navPos = $('#nav').offset().top;
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
                if (scrollTop >= navPos) {
                    var classNamee = $('#nav').attr('class');
                    console.log(classNamee);
                    if (classNamee === "nav") {
                        $("#nav").toggleClass('nav nav_sticky');
                        $("#right").toggleClass('right right_sticky');
                        $("#left").toggleClass('left left_stick');
                    }
                }

                if (scrollTop <= navPos) {
                    var className = $('#nav').attr('class');
                    console.log(className);
                    if (className === "nav_sticky") {
                        $("#nav").toggleClass('nav_sticky nav');
                        $("#right").toggleClass('right_sticky right');
                        $("#left").toggleClass('left left_stick');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here's my problem. This works perfectly for the top and right navs, however no matter what I try, the left nav continues to scroll when the others have stopped. I thought it may have been a typo in the css class, but when I looked in the inspector, the .toggleClass function doesn't even change the class on the #left element when it does on the other two. Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: you are getting the id of "left" here `$("#left").toggleClass('left left_stick');` but your id is "leftt"   `<div class="left" id="leftt">` in your html

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo in copy and pasting everything over, they are the same in the actual code.

Comment: then you can ignore my answer and check if @bwegs's answer work

Comment: Hi I added a couple of colors in order to test the classes only, let me  know if this is what are you looking for http://fiddle.jshell.net/Bbnva/

Answer (score 0):

If I copy/paste your sample code as-is to jsFiddle and run it, when you scroll down far enough, it does correctly toggle everything to `*_sticky` classes, but something about the negative `margin-right` on the `right` class element seems to reset the scroll to the top (at least in Chrome) when it flips between `.right` and `.right-stick`. When the scroll gets reset, it also reruns your event handeler and changes all the classes back.

Try removing these lines from your CSS and see if the behavior works right (it does in Chrome in a jsFiddle)

```
.right {
    ...
    /*margin-right: -538px;*/

.right-stick {
    ...
    /*margin-right: -538px;*/
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, the right one has always worked, it's the left one that doesn't. The strange thing is that they have essentially the same css just with left and right switched, so theres no reason one should work and the other shouldn't.